# Send data from Raspberry Pi Pico to computer via serial

Tags: python, serial-port, raspberry-pi-pico

I've looked everywhere for an answer to this question without much luck.

On my computer I have a python script running an infinite while loop.
On the Raspberry Pi Pico I'm reading a sensor value once a second.

I'd like to have access to the sensor readings from my computer, (whatever the current sensor reading is).

I'm not sure if it's best holding the values on some sort of register on the Pico or it's better to post them via serial or MQTT to the computer?

Potentially I'll be reading the sensor from the computer faster (0.5s) or slower (2s) than it's getting evaluated on the Pico.

Any ideas of what a good approach to accomplish this is?

Comment: Vote to close, as responses are likely to be opinion-based due to lack of any criteria.

Comment: What would criteria have looked like?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution, on the Pico side you open the serial port and print the sensor value every second, on the computer side you open the serial port and read it all the time, so you get the new values as they are sent by the Pico